# Complex number in mathematics tool for physics

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

My teacher give me like this in chapter complex number Sin z = 5/3 what does it mean? And how to solve that?

Comment: the associate lesson  probably gave you the generalized definition of sin using complex exponential, isn't it ?  ( + surely in the wikipedia page ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write $\sin z = \frac{1}{2i}(e^{iz} - e^{-iz})$. Then $\sin z = 5/3$ iff

$$e^{2iz} - \frac{10i}{3}e^{iz} - 1 = 0$$

Solve now for $e^{iz}$ and hence $z$.